# HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Get while webpage works Java

Tags: java, xmlhttprequest, httpclient, httpresponse

[image]I am tring to work with

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(method, context);
```

and getting this error

```
HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error [Date: Mon, 23 Nov 2015 08:30:11 GMT, 
Server: Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu), X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6-13ubuntu3.8, Set-Cookie: 
PHPSESSID=gtr71sg82bm9gd9987qeu9gp50; path=/, Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT, 
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, 
pre-check=0, Pragma: no-cache, Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100, 
Connection: Keep-Alive, Transfer-Encoding: chunked, Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8]}
```

The webpage appears as text a web browser and showing a valid Json text (all in one line)
but aftet using (f12) i also get an error 500 .

I cant check the server error because its not mine.

I had search for previous error like mine and found : [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954331/apache-httpclient-is-throwng-http-500s-but-cant-reproduce-in-a-browser) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30258554/500-internal-error-from-http-post-request) 
and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421234/httpclient-http-1-1-500-internal-server-error) and many more

All of them are offering changing the header 
have tried changing the header - but it didn't solved my problem.

How do i know which header do i need ?
What else could i try to fix it ?

more details

```
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 25 Nov 2015 09:46:41 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.6-13ubuntu3.8

Request Headers
view source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:PHPSESSID=gb9n33a3qbnlqfdnn6kretsgr3
Host:cc.avidtrak.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an actual answer since I cannot comment, but you can try open dev tool (f12 in Chrome) and open network tab, request to the url and see the request headers (since you said it works with browser request), and compare with the request you make from Java

Comment: adding more information on chrome - after oppening webpage shoing a valid json content. but in the chrome dev tool - i also get an error 500 (Type Document)

Comment: Did you open Devtool and try request that webpage to see the request headers from network tab?

Comment: please check the added picture

Comment: what does the browser show when you open dev tool? Also 500?

Comment: Yes it does - but the text inside the webpage is fine

Comment: That's really strange. Can you post the full response here? You can click the request in network tab and see response and response headers

Comment: Could it be the authorization? It uses cookie/session state when you login and by using a httpclient request it doesn't have permission thus generate the exception?

Comment: Don't know i will contant the 3rd party website for more details thanks for your help up to now